# Select a single number from a group by comparing time stamps

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an xlsx sheet (using MS Office 2010) with around 10-15K rows and multiple columns. I want to consider two columns to filter this data but need data from all the existing columns. Sheet looks like [image: sample sheet]

The id column can have duplicate records. The rule I want to apply is:

1) For the set of duplicate ids in column id, select only 1 row which has highest value in corresponding timestamp column.

2) So as result this should give only distinct ids with hisghest timestamp among it's set of duplicate values.

3) Considering the data in the sheet, the result should have only two rows that I have filled in with yellow color.

Can you please help me on how to setup rule to do this in excel?

Comment: when I sort col A and then try to sort col B, it changes sorting done on col A. I need to find a way to sort col A and then sort col B (desc) for each unique value in col A. Finally select top row for each unique value in col A. I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by id then timestamp (descending). Add a new column after B and use

```
 =COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2).
```

Filter that column to show only 1's

Answer (score 1):

Do a descending sort on Columns A and B and then use Remove Duplicates on Column A only. The highest values should be the first found, and anything else will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting for a Range from A2 to A24 you can use:

```
=B2=MAX(B$2:B$24*(A$2:A$24=A2))
```

If you have any questions, just ask ;)